# Custom Post Type Categories Listed Across two columns

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I have an issue where I have a page that looks like the attached.

I am using the following code to achieve this

```
<?php
                    $args = array(
                        'type'                     => 'episodes',
                        'child_of'                 => 0,
                        'parent'                   => '',
                        'orderby'                  => 'name',
                        'order'                    => 'ASC',
                        'hide_empty'               => 1,
                        'hierarchical'             => 1,
                        'taxonomy'                 => 'episode_categories',
                        'pad_counts'               => false );
                    $categories = get_categories($args);


                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $url = get_term_link($category);?>

                        <div class="categories__row flex xs:block space-x-10 xs:space-x-0 xs:space-y-6">
                            <div class="categories__item w-1/2 xs:w-full">
                                <div class="article text-2xl sm:text-xl xxs:text-base">
                                    <h2 class="text-4xl sm:text-28px xxs:text-xl font-bold leading-none"><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h2>
                                    <p>There are <strong>22</strong> podcasts in this category</p>
                                </div><!-- /.article -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="categories__item w-1/2 xs:w-full">
                                <div class="article text-2xl sm:text-xl xxs:text-base">
                                    <h2 class="text-4xl sm:text-28px xxs:text-xl font-bold leading-none"><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h2>
                                    <p>There are <strong>22</strong> podcasts in this category</p>
                                </div><!-- /.article -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

However, what I want to achieve is the ability to count and loop out the categories from left to right and so on. So, on row 1 we should see Augmented Reality and then business. Line two should then be F1 and VR.

I have looked across some similar posts on Stack Overflow but none that are quite like this requirement. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

[image: Current View on loop result]

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but I think you just need to move your loop to inside the row container, something like below:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'type'                     => 'episodes',
  'child_of'                 => 0,
  'parent'                   => '',
  'orderby'                  => 'name',
  'order'                    => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty'               => 1,
  'hierarchical'             => 1,
  'taxonomy'                 => 'episode_categories',
  'pad_counts'               => false
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
?>

<div class="categories__row flex xs:block space-x-10 xs:space-x-0 xs:space-y-6">

  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

    <div class="categories__item w-1/2 xs:w-full">
      <div class="article text-2xl sm:text-xl xxs:text-base">
        <h2 class="text-4xl sm:text-28px xxs:text-xl font-bold leading-none">
          <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category); ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name; ?>
          </a>
        </h2>
        <p>There are <strong>22</strong> podcasts in this category</p>
      </div><!-- /.article -->
    </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</div> <!-- END .categories__row -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciated. This basically puts the items (4 of them as at the moment there are 4 active categories) in one row. I need it to be two items in a single row

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code on an instance of WordPress and since I'm unsure on the CSS you are using, I'm not sure how simple this would be to implement. But a combination of moving the position for the `foreach` and potentially CSS grid could be useful here.

The position of the `foreach` in the previous example is similar to what I would do. I think the items aren't falling onto a new line because you might be missing a css property on your `flex` helper class. Are you using `flex-wrap: wrap;`? It sounds like you might need to add that. If that still doesn't work, then there's something else at play

https://codepen.io/jamie-endeavour/pen/mdVOqGe

As I say, you might be able to save yourself some work with Grid, I've supplied a (very rough) example on Codepen with static HTML.

Hope this helps! Feel free to shout back if it's not right

Comment: Thanks for this Jamie, the site uses TailWind CSS and understand your approach here on the codepen. However, what I am trying to achieve here is for the loop, to loop out a row that contains two items, then ends. The Creates another Row, with the next two items, and then another row with two items and so on...What I essentially am looking for is a way for the page to loop out a new room each time which contains two categories within the row.